# DispatchEvent in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an event so that I can add listeners for when an event occurs. There will be different scenarios that trigger the event and therefore would be tracking what triggered the event and handle it appropriately. However, I tried adding the dispatchEvent within a function that occurs within a loop and I am receiving an InvalidState error. Anyone cares to explain what causes this error and why it is happening here. You can see my code below

```
//create event
var event = new Event('tableRowAdded');

//get element reference
var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');

//set model
var model = [{jsonData},{jsonData},{jsonData}];

//validate model and then start creating table
function addRowsToTable(DOMTable, rowData){
    //stop execution if rowdata null
    if(rowData == null || DOMTable == null){
        return;
    }

    var currentRowCount = DOMTable.rows.length;

    //add empty row to table
    var tr = DOMTable.insertRow(currentRowCount);
    tr.id = "data_row_" + currentRowCount;

    //add columns to table
    //first cell is used for error data
    var td = tr.insertCell(0);

    //traineeCode
    td = tr.insertCell(1);
    td.innerHTML = rowData.TRAINEE_CODE; //this is one of the json keys within the json data
}

function populateTableFromJSON(){
    var count = model.length;

    //loop over json array to populate table
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        addRowsToTable(table, model[i]);
        //dispatch event occured
        table.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

This is the error received

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched.

Comment: Create a complete yet minimal example. Your demo isn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you need to change:

```
table.dispatchEvent(event);
```

to

```
table.dispatchEvent(new Event('tableRowAdded'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Very messed up the example you posted.
You're calling a method where you perform object validation:

```
if(rowData == null || DOMTable == null){
    return;
}
```

but at the same time you're ignoring the validation trying to dispatch the event anyway on the next line:

```
 table.dispatchEvent(event);
```

The event object in javascript have some properties changed after being dispatched that's because the event should reflect its current state at several phases. Try to call this way:

```
table.dispatchEvent(new Event('tableRowAdded'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little dated, but I  thought I would at least answer it incase someone else stumbles upon this post.

The reason you are getting the error is because you are trying to dispatch the event to the same object (the table) over and over again. Try dispatching it to each row.

EDIT:  Here's your code modified.  I moved the dispatch inside the loop where the rows are added and added an event listener to the table.

```
//create event
var event = new Event('tableRowAdded');

//get table
var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
// set event listener
table.addEventListener("tableRowAdded", function(e) {
  handler code
});

//set model
var model = [{jsonData},{jsonData},{jsonData}];

//validate model and then start creating table
function addRowsToTable(DOMTable, rowData){
    //stop execution if rowdata null
    if(rowData == null || DOMTable == null){
        return;
    }

    var currentRowCount = DOMTable.rows.length;

    //add empty row to table
    var tr = DOMTable.insertRow(currentRowCount);
    tr.id = "data_row_" + currentRowCount;

    //add columns to table
    //first cell is used for error data
    var td = tr.insertCell(0);

    //traineeCode
    td = tr.insertCell(1);
    td.innerHTML = rowData.TRAINEE_CODE; //this is one of the json keys within the json data

  // dispatch event
    tr.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function populateTableFromJSON(){
    var count = model.length;

    //loop over json array to populate table
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        addRowsToTable(table, model[i]);
    }
}
```